# JQuery tablesorter zebra stripes inside tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, tablesorter

I have a web page that uses JQuery tabs and inside 3 of the tabs are tables that I am trying to use JQuery tablesorter with zebra stripes.  The first tab has a table that works correctly.  The 3rd and 4th tab tables get sorted correctly but the first time you view the tab the tables don't have the zebra stripes but are sorted correctly.  If you click on one of the column headers to sort the table, it sorts and then the zebra stripes work from then on.  I am trying to figure out how to get the stripes to work the first time the tab is viewed.  At first I had all the tablesorter code in the $.ready code but when that didn't work I tried just sorting it when the tab is selected.  Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
      switch (ui.index) {
        case 3:
          $("#bTable").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra'] , sortList: [[0,0]]});
          break;    
        case 4:
          $("#cTable").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra'] , sortList: [[0,0]]});
          break;
      }
    }});
});

$(document).ready(function()     {
  $("#aTable").tablesorter({ 
      widgets: ['zebra'] 
  });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you just initialize tablesorter before setting up the tabs?

Comment: Thanks Mottie, moving the tabs() function after the tablesorter fixed this problem.

Comment: @Chris as a good practice you should always post your ans and mark them correct so that other will find it easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqueryui Tabs with Tablesorter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677472/jqueryui-tabs-with-tablesorter)