# jqueryui Tabs with Tablesorter

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using jquery ui tabs with the tablesorter 2.0 plugin to obtain sort abilities on a dynamically populated html table but the sort only happens on the first tab upon page load. The other tabs do not sort or obtain the zebra striping form the tablesorter.

html:

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="ftp-type.aspx?type=ftponly">Ftp Only</a></li>
      <li><a href="ftp-type.aspx?type=Billing Only">Billing Only</a></li>
      <li><a href="ftp-type.aspx?type=Variance">Variance</a></li>
      <li><a href="ftp-type.aspx?type=adjust">Adj Only</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
      ajaxOptions: {cache: false},
      load: function() 
      {
          $("#ReportTable").tablesorter();
      }
});
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zebra widget only applies to visible rows, so you'll need to trigger the `applyWIdgets` method. And I'm going to assume you are using jQuery UI 1.10.2 and jQuery 2.0, where you can use the `activate` callback ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/786/)):

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var $t = ui.newPanel.find('table');
        // make sure there is a table in the tab
        if ($t.length) {
            if ($t[0].config) {
                // update zebra widget
                $t.trigger('applyWidgets');
            } else {
                // initialize tablesorter
                $t.tablesorter({
                    theme: 'blue',
                    widgets: ["zebra"]
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Update: Oops, if the table is in the first tab, use this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/794/)):

```
var tablesorterOptions = {
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ["zebra"]
};

$("#tabs").tabs({
    create: function (event, ui) {
        var $t = ui.panel.find('table');
        if ($t.length) {
            $t.tablesorter(tablesorterOptions);
        }
    },
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var $t = ui.newPanel.find('table');
        if ($t.length) {
            if ($t[0].config) {
                $t.trigger('applyWidgets');
            } else {
                $t.tablesorter(tablesorterOptions);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mottie. The code works but not on the first tab on the inital load. Any idea why?

Comment: @Mottie you a real life safer..thumbs up for you