# Multiple tablesorter tables in Jquery UI tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, tablesorter

I have 3 tables, of that I am using 1st table to display in one of the Jquery UI tabs and 2 other tables in another tab. 
Issue is only one (last or 3rd one ) of the 2 tables show up . The one above flashes off and doesnt display back.

Here is my doc ready function:

```
  \$(document).ready(
  function(){

  \$("#tabs").tabs({

     create: function (event, ui) {
          var \$t = ui.panel.find('table');
               if (\$t.length) {
              \$t.tablesorter(tablesorterOptions);
          }
      },
      activate: function (event, ui) {
          var \$t = ui.newPanel.find('table');
          if (\$t.length) {
              if (\$t[0].config) {
                  \$t.trigger('applyWidgets');
              } else  {
                  \$("#table3").tablesorter(tablesorterOptions);
                   \$("#table1").tablesorter(tablesorterOptions1);
                    \$("#tavble2").tablesorter(tablesorterOptions2)

                   }
          }
      }
});
```

My table declarations have THEAD,TBODY with ids, table1,table2,table3 and class tablesorter.

Jquery UI is same as shown in the demos on the jquery websites. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677472/jqueryui-tabs-with-tablesorter

Comment: No. Its different Mottie.

Comment: I want to use different tablesorter options for these 3 tables.So I am using :

Comment: \$("#table3").tablesorter(tablesorterOptions); Is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: Please provide the entire code required to reproduce the issue, or an online demo such as jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured this one out. I had type mismatch in tablesorter's filter columns. So it wasn't displaying the table but others were getting displayed.
Thanks!!!